# The center of energy of a closed system maintains constant velocity in the vacuum of space. How can a warp drive overcome this rule?

Tags: momentum, warp-drives

In the following paper [Introducing Physical Warp Drives by Alexey Bobrick, Gianni Martire](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06824)
they state

> 5.2.  Constructing warp drives: Warp drives, being inertially moving shells of normal or exotic material, do not have any  natural  way  of  changing  their  velocities.   They  are  just  like  any  other  types  of inertially moving objects.  Similarly, just like for any other massive objects, achieving a  certain  velocity  for  a  warp  drive  requires  an  externally  applied  force  or,  more practically,  some  form  of  propulsion.   Propulsion  may  be  realized,  for  example,  by an interaction with a bosonic field, or regular gaseous or plasma material

And

> 5.3. Finally, since all warp drive objects require propulsion in order to accelerate, any practical implementation of such objects would have to be asymmetric in shape, since the  back  part  would  have  to  accommodate  a  propellant  exhaust  system.

Is there anything wrong with those conclusions and has all this talk about Warp-drive been misleading since it seems normal propulsion is still required to move said warp-bubble?

Comment: See this question and the associated answers, especially those by Jerry Schirmer and myself: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119522/how-does-warp-drive-not-violate-special-relativity-causality-constraints

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to have a classical propulsion system on a ship with a warp drive. A movement of the ship is caused by deformation of space-time itself. The space-time contracts in front of the ship and expand behind it. As a result, the ship is pulled ahead by these changes in space-time geometry.